# Google Cloud Role to access specific pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to specify a Role in such a way that it allows you to listen to a very specific Pub/Sub topic rather than all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Roles apply to a resource, so the most adequate question would be "Can a policy be set into a Pub/Sub resource?"

The answer is yes, and it's done through the Pub/Sub API method [`projects.topics.setIamPolicy`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/setIamPolicy). To that endpoint, you must pass a [policy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy), which will allow you to set bindings for the roles `Owner`, `Editor`, or `Viewer`.